# How can I allow a user to create a user, but not view all users?

Tags: 7, users

In Drupal 7, I can set the 'administer users' permission to a certain role. However I do not want this role to be able to view and filter/search all users in my Drupal site. The `admin/people/create` only, but no `admin/people`  page should be accessible because they have the capability to filter the administrator role! And able to edit it in turn.

Is there a module that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Subuser module](http://drupal.org/project/subuser) can help to achieve this goal. A user that is allowed to create a sub users can manage them as well.

Comment: This crashed my test site. I will have to try it again if I have time. Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure if this module helped. I tested this mod for drupal 6, configured a particular role to be able to 'create subuser' from the permissions page. Logging in using this role, I cannot see where to create a subuser! Am I missing something else?

Comment: Its so much better to use drupal 6 and I am able to achive this using only the administersusersbyrole module in conjuntion with role_delegation module.